# Cancel button Android Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, ionic-framework, qr-code

I'm using ionic 3 for my application and especially the plugin [@ionic-native/barcode-scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/)

On IOS I have got a cancel button at the bottom of the screen : 
[image: ios view]

**The problem is that button isn't present on android :**
[image: android view]

Comment: `Android` tends to have more than just one hardware button ...where `<` means `cancel`.

Comment: Yeah I know but when I'm pressing this button, my app exit ...

Comment: while there is no `ParentActivity` defined in the `Manifest.xml`, is it supposed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix that you have to handle the back button event with the [platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/) plugin.

```
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public platform : Platform){
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {

    });
}
```

You can also set a boolean to know if you're scanning or not.